# How can I create a Mono project compatible winforms app using dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I'd like to create a winforms app on windows using the dotnet command line which is compatible with the Mono project running on Linux. In my particular case th framework should be .NET framework 4.7.2.

If I use Visual Studio I can create a winforms project specifically for the .NET framework. However if I use `dotnet new winforms` to create a new winforms app I can set the framework with `-f` only to either `netcoreapp3.1` or `net5.0`. It is just about scaffolding the app project, not developing it.

Can I run them on under Linux using Mono?

Comment: The dotnet cli tool is exclusively for .NET Core (and as such .NET 5 and onwards) development, not .NET Framework, so the answer is no, you cannot create a .NET Framework 4.7.2 WinForms project using `dotnet`. If you desperately need a (new) WinForms on Linux I'd recommend you use something like MonoDevelop. But if you don't desperately need WinForms then I'd recommend you use something like Avalonia or Xamarin Forms

Comment: I've had a look into MonoDevelop already. But it seems to be unmaintained. At least the [github repo](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop) is archived. I'm not really happy using a tool which is not maintained anymore.